# Piecewise function, prove function is continuous at 0

Tags: functions, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Consider the piecewise function: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x$ is rational}\\
-x & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$

This produces a function that jumps rapidly between $x$ and $-x$ throughout its graph. It can be shown that this function is discontinuous for all nonzero values of $x$. I do not need to prove this, but I do need to prove that this function is continuos at $0$.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$, since $|f(x)| = |x|$, and $f(0) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall  \epsilon \exists \delta >0 :|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon\\ |x-0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon\\
|x|<\delta  \Rightarrow |\pm x-0|<\epsilon \\
|x|<\delta  \Rightarrow |\pm 1||x|<\epsilon\\\delta <\epsilon $$

Answer (score 0):

$|f(x)-f (0)|=|x|$.

Your  turn!